# How to change "Number Format" in Gnome 2

Tags: gnome, locale

I require to change my Number format in my CentOS 6.0 box. I am using "gnome desktop environment" version 2.28.2. I want to know from where can I change the default Number Format of the system.

I want to change this because in my system the number values are automatically changing as per default number format and I don't know what is that format.

In windows it is possible from control panel:
[image]

I tried searching into
1. System-> Administration-> Language
2. System-> Preferences-> Keyboard
3. System-> Preferences-> Input Method
But the required settings are not there.

If it is not possible by GUI then how to do it with command-line?

**Update:**
Being specific, I want `Digit grouping: 123456789` i.e. NOT including any comma, which is shown in above windows numbering format.

Comment: Why Downvote ??

Answer (score 2):

**Linux** refers to these settings as ***system-locale***.

You can change your system locale by,

- set environment variables to control the system locale. You can set these variables to be system-wide, or on a per-session basis:

`LC_ALL`

Overrides all `LC_*` environment variables with the given value

```
LC_CTYPE
```

Character classification and case conversion

```
LC_COLLATE
```

Collation (sort) order

```
LC_TIME
```

Date and time formats

```
LC_NUMERIC
```

Non-monetary numeric formats

```
LC_MONETARY
```

Monetary formats

```
LC_MEASUREMENT
```

Measurement units (Metric or Other)

```
LANG
```

The default value, which is used when either `LC_ALL` is not set, or an applicable value for `LC_*` is not set

```
TZ
```

Time zone

You can use the command `locale` to show your current locale.

`locale -a` displays all the locales that are currently installed on the machine. Make sure that the locale you select for `LANG` and `LC_ALL` is in the list that is returned by the command locale -a. The values that locale uses and returns are **case sensitive**, therefore copy them exactly when assigning them to an environment variable.

## Consult the `man-pages` for more information like given below

Spefically for what you asked for, set

`mon_grouping`: Defines the size of each group of digits in formatted monetary  quantities.

> ```
>         mon_grouping   Formatted Value  ISO C String
>
>          3;-1       123456'789       "\3\177"
>          3          123'456'789      "\3"
>          3;2;-1         1234'56'789      "\3\2\177"
>          3;2        12'34'56'789     "\3\2"
>          -1         1234567898       "\177"
> ```

Therefore your case should be

in `LC_MONETARY`

```
mon_grouping           -1
```

and also in `LC_NUMERIC`

```
grouping                -1
```

### EDIT: To change these settings, edit your **locale** config file

```
/usr/share/i18n/locales/<your_locale>
```

Comment: but those variables are showing blank value when I am using echo Eg. `echo $LC_NUMERIC`

Comment: Run `locale` as a normal user.

Comment: please go through the update.

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but how do I change this `mon_grouping` and `grouping` variables? Please edit accordingly.

Comment: did above solution work for you?

Comment: I am checking that ... I think it needs logoff the current session. So waiting for some pending work to clear. Thanks btw

Comment: note that this is not valid for gnome3, which overrides system-wide locale settings.